# Elasticsearch timestamp query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I can query elasticsearch with this command,

```
{
   "query" : {
       "query_string" : {
           "default_field" : "Domain",
           "query" : "Domain : edelinefs"
       }
   }
}
```

but I can't query with filter @timestamp "2017-04-10 00:00:00.000" to "2017-04-11 23:59:59.000". Any body can help me ?

Comment: Can you update your question with `filter` query you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) filter like so:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "Domain",
            "query": "edelinefs"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2017-04-10T00:00:00.000",
              "lte": "2017-04-11T23:59:59.000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "[query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line" : 8,
        "col" : 9
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line" : 8,
    "col" : 9
  },
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: Try with this updated query: `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "Domain",
            "query": "edelinefs"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2017-04-10T00:00:00.000",
              "lte": "2017-04-11T23:59:59.000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`